# Unable to display data

Tags: php, yii

I'm using yii framework for a project and I want to display a token amount based upon the user id of the person logged in.

Whats happening is the echo's in the code display on a blank page and it is successfully getting the user ID from the session. But apart from the echos the page is totally blank. Not sure how to get it to display.

```
public function actionIndex() { 
    echo 'hello world';
    $_id = Yii::app()->user->getId();
    echo '   user id =' . $_id;
    $model = Tokens::model()->findByAttributes(array('UserID'=>$_id));
    echo ' model =';
    if ($model === null)
        throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');
    return $model;



//     $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Tokens');
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

Using mvc style and the views are made and do work as they're the default created by the framework when using Gii to create crud functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove `return $model;` and dont use `$dataProvider` as renderer array. You have to use `$model`.

```
$this->render('index', array(
    'model' => $model,
));
```

Now, in your view file `index.php` print $model to check what data you are getting

```
print_r($model);
```

Comment: It shows the page layout, content wise it puts out this but the data in it is correct

Comment: Tokens Object ( [_new:CActiveRecord:private] => [_attributes:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [TokenID] => 1 [UserID] => 59 [TokenAmount] => 22 ) [_related:CActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_c:CActiveRecord:private] => [_pk:CActiveRecord:private] => 1 [_alias:CActiveRecord:private] => t [_errors:CModel:private] => Array ( ) [_validators:CModel:private] => [_scenario:CModel:private] => update [_e:CComponent:private] => [_m:CComponent:private] => )

Comment: yes because you have print the $model. Now, you can retreive this data and show as you want using html

Comment: So how do I only display the token amount and not the token ID or user ID?

Comment: Use echo $model->TokenAmount;

Answer (score 0):

`return $model;` is your problem, perhaps you mean `echo $model;` instead.

the return exits the function, so this->render is never called